# K-means clustering with predefined dataset

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I'm trying to cluster the movies data set that comes with the package "ggplot2" in R. I will be using k-means. The column names that comes with this data set are :

```
[1] "title"       "year"        "length"      "budget"      "rating"     
 [6] "votes"       "r1"          "r2"          "r3"          "r4"         
[11] "r5"          "r6"          "r7"          "r8"          "r9"         
[16] "r10"         "mpaa"        "Action"      "Animation"   "Comedy"     
[21] "Drama"       "Documentary" "Romance"     "Short"
```

Would you think it is a good idea to do clustering based on the movie genre ? I'm kind of lost and don't know where to start off. Any advice ?

Comment: it is not clear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I'm only trying to bring in some ideas to have more knowledge on what clustering is and does. Like in this case of data set, what would you do to cluster it and what questions would you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out what makes a *good* cluster.

There are millions of way to cluster this data set. Because you can preprocess the data differently, use different algorithms, distances, and so on.

Without your guidance, the clustering algorithm will just do something, and likely return a completely useless result!

So you need to first get a clear objective: what is a good clustering?

Then you can try to adapt the data such that the clustering algorithms optimize for this objective. For k-means, you need to do all of this in preprocessing. For hclust you can also choose distance functions that match your desires.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: Yes, I think that this is an interesting project. Working with this dataset could be a cool way to learn about different data mining techniques.

To answer your second question, here is some advice. Clustering is an unsupervised learning technique. Learning is unsupervised when the target variable (in this case, the target variable might be the genre of the movie) is unknown. However, looking at the columns that you listed, it seems like you do have the genre information. With that in mind, you have two options. First, you could pretend like you don't have the genre information. In this case you would apply k-means to the rest of the data. After the clustering is done, you could evaluate how well the algorithm done by comparing it to the known genre. Second, you could treat this problem as a classification problem. In this case, you would use the the genre information to learn a model that can predict the genre. You might already know this, but I just wanted to say it.

To give you some advice on the clustering problem specifically, I first would want to know what the 'r1', ..., 'r10' variables represent. Are they numeric variables or categorical? K-means has two steps: one where you assign data points to the centroid that is nearest to it and one where you calculate the new centroid by taking the mean of all data points in a cluster. Does taking the mean of these variables make sense?

With that in mind, I would recommend first choosing the variables that you want to use in the clustering algorithm. Then write the following functions: one that can calculate the distance between two points, one that can assign an observation to the nearest centroid, and one that can recalculate the centroids based on the assignments.

Comment: Thank you Michael. That clarifies some of the doubts. To answer your question: r1-10. Multiplying by ten gives percentile (to nearest 10%) of users who rated this movie a 1.